# MySQL equivalent of ORACLES rank()

Tags: oracle, mysql

Oracle has 2 functions - rank() and dense_rank() - which i've found very useful for some applications. I am doing something in mysql now and was wondering if they have something equivalent to those?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing directly equivalent, but you can fake it with some (not terribly efficient) self-joins.  Some sample code from a [collection of MySQL query howtos](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php?&bw=1280#460):

```
SELECT v1.name, v1.votes, COUNT(v2.votes) AS Rank
FROM votes v1
JOIN votes v2 ON v1.votes < v2.votes OR (v1.votes=v2.votes and v1.name = v2.name)
GROUP BY v1.name, v1.votes
ORDER BY v1.votes DESC, v1.name DESC;
+-------+-------+------+
| name  | votes | Rank |
+-------+-------+------+
| Green |    50 |    1 |
| Black |    40 |    2 |
| White |    20 |    3 |
| Brown |    20 |    3 |
| Jones |    15 |    5 |
| Smith |    10 |    6 |
+-------+-------+------+
```

Comment: I wish there was a better solution, but this will have to do

Comment: @younes0: If you look at White and Brown, you'll see that it is (correctly) placing a tie at rank 3, then skipping to rank 5.

Comment: @chaos okay so I guess that skipping to rank 5 is oracle rank()'s default behavior

Answer (score 1):

how about this "dense_rank implement" in MySQL

```
CREATE TABLE `person` (  
 `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,  
 `first_name` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,  
 `age` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,  
 `gender` char(1) DEFAULT NULL);

INSERT INTO `person` VALUES 
(1,'Bob',25,'M'),
(2,'Jane',20,'F'),
(3,'Jack',30,'M'),
(4,'Bill',32,'M'),
(5,'Nick',22,'M'),
(6,'Kathy',18,'F'),
(7,'Steve',36,'M'),
(8,'Anne',25,'F'),
(9,'Mike',25,'M');
```

the data before dense_rank() like this

```
mysql> select * from person;
+------+------------+------+--------+
| id   | first_name | age  | gender |
+------+------------+------+--------+
|    1 | Bob        |   25 | M      |
|    2 | Jane       |   20 | F      |
|    3 | Jack       |   30 | M      |
|    4 | Bill       |   32 | M      |
|    5 | Nick       |   22 | M      |
|    6 | Kathy      |   18 | F      |
|    7 | Steve      |   36 | M      |
|    8 | Anne       |   25 | F      |
|    9 | Mike       |   25 | M      |
+------+------------+------+--------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

the data after dense_rank() like this,including "partition by" function

```
+------------+--------+------+------+
| first_name | gender | age  | rank |
+------------+--------+------+------+
| Anne       | F      |   25 |    1 |
| Jane       | F      |   20 |    2 |
| Kathy      | F      |   18 |    3 |
| Steve      | M      |   36 |    1 |
| Bill       | M      |   32 |    2 |
| Jack       | M      |   30 |    3 |
| Mike       | M      |   25 |    4 |
| Bob        | M      |   25 |    4 |
| Nick       | M      |   22 |    6 |
+------------+--------+------+------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

the query statement is

```
select first_name,t1.gender,age,FIND_IN_SET(age,t1.age_set) as rank from person t2,
(select gender,group_concat(age order by age desc) as age_set from person group by gender) t1
where t1.gender=t2.gender
order by t1.gender,rank
```