# How do I collapse these rows in my database?

Tags: mysql, database

I want to wind up with a set of data that shows the user by the latest timestamp. Here is my SQL

```
SELECT
t2.unit AS UnitNo,
t1.lname AS Name,
t4.code_id AS ActivityNo,
t5.activity_id AS Active,
t4.call_no AS CallNo,
t4.acn_id AS CallStatusNo,
t2.unit_id AS UnitId,
Max(t5.created) created
FROM user AS t1

Inner Join unit AS t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id
Left Join dispatch AS t3 ON t2.unit_id = t3.unit_id
Left Join incident AS t4 ON t4.incident_id = t3.incident_id
Left Join unit_log AS t5 ON t2.unit_id = t5.unit_id
WHERE

t1.id = 1
GROUP BY
t2.unit,
t1.lname,
t4.code_id,
t5.activity_id,
t4.call_no,
t4.acn_id,
t2.unit_id
ORDER BY created desc
```

I've included a pic to show what I'm after. What I should end up with are 2 rows. There are 2 users on this system currently, so I should see only one MAX(created) row per user. Even after grouping, I can't get get down past what you see here.

Comment: You would need to remove columns which are different for each row. EG 'Anderson rows' - UnitNo, Active and Created are different which means they cannot be grouped.

Comment: The thing is, I need those columns. Would a sub query give me what I need?

Comment: @Nan is Active field useful or it can be avoided?

Comment: @FayeqAliKhan, actually, that is the most important field of them all

Comment: @Nan can u define the purpose of Active.. can we use some aggregate function like max or min over Active ?

Comment: If I could avoid that one column, I wouldn't have so many rows to deal with. That column is coming from a log table and it's needed to show the current status, based on the max timestamp

Comment: Active is showing the unit_id current status. That's why it's so important

Comment: @NaN Sorry but what does 1 , 2 , 3 for anderson tell?

Comment: @Nan we can get your required behavior if Active column is adjusted

Comment: @Nan but as u say if there are two users it means they can only single Active status isn't it . Anderson can have Active status as 1 or 2 or 3... can not b all of them togather?

Comment: @Nan can we use Max(Active) ... it will show the latest Active status .. does it go with ur business use cases

Comment: That's a good thought, Fayeq, but unfortunately, a user can theoretically have a status of 15 one minute and a 1 the next, so that wouldn't be dependable

Comment: I think I can get what I'm after with a sub query... I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a MySQL equivalent to a ranking function. Take a look at this answer and the links listed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320173/mysql-equivalent-of-oracles-rank

Comment: Thanks Chicago. Going there now

Comment: @NaN but the problem is that, as u said if there are two users then you want result set with 2 rows... its conflicting with user and active columns

Comment: I guess I don't understand why, if I'm grouping on all columns except for the created column, why I the Active column is not showing the correct value

Comment: @Nan because you are using aggregate function over created Max... so basically it picks the highest created value..

Comment: So can this not be done? Is there no solution to this problem that you can see?

Comment: Can u explain what you want from the tables in simple english.. what is required output so i can put up some solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want one row, you have to pick which unit ID and activity ID you want displayed. You are using a one to many join, so of course your rows will be multiplied.

You need to rank your rows by user and timestamp. try the following (just replace the all columns line)

```
 SELECT *
    FROM (
    SELECT 
@rn:=if(@prv=product_id, @rn+1, 1) AS rId, 
@prv:=user_id AS user_id, 
ALL your other columns,
timestamp                                                                               
    FROM
      (SELECT t2.unit AS UnitNo,
              t1.lname AS Name,
              t4.code_id AS ActivityNo,
              t5.activity_id AS Active,
              t4.call_no AS CallNo,
              t4.acn_id AS CallStatusNo,
              t2.unit_id AS UnitId,
              Max(t5.created) created
       FROM USER AS t1
       INNER JOIN unit AS t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id
       LEFT JOIN DISPATCH AS t3 ON t2.unit_id = t3.unit_id
       LEFT JOIN incident AS t4 ON t4.incident_id = t3.incident_id
       LEFT JOIN unit_log AS t5 ON t2.unit_id = t5.unit_id
       INNER JOIN
         (SELECT unit_id
          FROM unit_log
          WHERE t1.id = 1
          GROUP BY t2.unit,
                   t1.lname,
                   t4.code_id,
                   t5.activity_id,
                   t4.call_no,
                   t4.acn_id,
                   t2.unit_id
          ORDER BY created DESC ) b
       JOIN
         (SELECT @prv:=0, @rn:=0)tmp
       ORDER BY user_id,
                TIMESTAMP DESC) a
    WHERE rid<=1
```

Comment: Adrian, thank you. I was just coming back to answer my own question. I also used a join and now have it working. Thank you for your answer, and I'll credit you for it.

Comment: NP. if you your data structure allows you to do it with a join, it's much faster. The method above however works for whenever you need to rank something by something else (most active users by month, highest revenue customers by year etc. I initially wanted to suggest a inner join with a sub query containing user ID and max(timestamp) but am not familiar with the data structure.