# Are there any functions in MySQL like dense_rank() and row_number() like Oracle?

Tags: mysql, database, row-number

Are there any functions in MySQL like `dense_rank()` and `row_number()` like those provided by Oracle and other DBMS?

I want to generate an id within the query, but in MySQL these functions are not there. Is there an alternative?

Comment: Simple answer is NO you have to use user defined variables and calculate manually in query

Comment: How to calculate manually in query can you tell me i am new to mysql @MKhalidJunaid

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1320196/1816093

Comment: Rownum in mysql: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/procedure-rownum.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mysql doesn't have them, but you can simulate `row_number()` with the following expression that uses a user defined variable:

```
(@row := ifnull(@row, 0) + 1)
```

like this:

```
select *, (@row := ifnull(@row, 0) + 1) row_number
from mytable
order by id
```

but if you're reusing the session, `@row` will still be set, so you'll need to reset it like this instead:

```
set @row := 0;
select *, (@row := @row + 1) row_number
from mytable
order by 1;
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/62001/9).

`dense_rank()` is possible but a train wreck; I advise handling that requirement in the app layer.

Comment: But the numbers are keep on increasing how many times i execute the query.

Comment: @CSiva see edit for how to overcome the "ever-increasing row number" problem.

Answer (score 5):

We have now..

```
select ename, sal, dense_rank() over (order by sal desc)rnk
from emp2 e
order by rnk;
```

Answer (score 1):

In `MySql` you dont have `dense_rank()` or `row_number()` like the one in `Oracle`.

But you can create the same functionality through `SQL` query:

Here is an article doing the same:

[`dense_rank()`](http://www.folkstalk.com/2013/03/grouped-dense-rank-function-mysql-sql-query.html)
[`row_number()`](http://www.folkstalk.com/2013/03/grouped-row-number-function-mysql.html)

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't support these functions, but you can mimic them yourself. Shamelessly link to my solution to [ROW_NUMBER, RANK and DENSE_RANK functions in MySQL](http://kennethxu.blogspot.com/2016/04/analytical-function-in-mysql-rownumber.html)

Answer (score 0):

`DENSE_RANK()` function is available in MySQL version 8.0. So if you're using MySQL version 8.0 you can run this command,

```
SELECT name, DENSE_RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY value ) my_rank FROM table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL version 8 now has ROW_NUMBER.
[Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number)

EXAMPLE:

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s.Id) AS 'row_num', 
    s.product,
    s.title
FROM supplies AS S
```