# implement dense rank with mysql view

Tags: mysql, sql

We migrating database from sql server to mysql.
In previous database they created views. In views they used dense_rank() but there is no function like dense_rank.I have implemented dense rank in mysql query. but i have to implement dense rank into view. If anyone had solution.please help me.

Comment: sample data and the expected result would help.

Comment: Any of the standard solutions would do.

Comment: @bhushan Please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32494950/are-there-any-functions-in-mysql-like-dense-rank-and-row-number-like-oracle , you can use view instead of table .

Answer (score 0):

Why are you moving to MySQL?  There are other free databases that are more performing and support the full range of ANSI functions.  But, you can do this using a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(distinct t2.<order by column>)
        from t t2
        where t2.<partition by column> = t.<partition by column> and
              t2.<order by column> <= t.<order by column>
      ) as dense_rank
from t;
```