# Why can't I use dense_rank for SQL 'rank scores'?

Tags: mysql, window-functions, dense-rank

I'm using the dense_rank function in SQL to solve the leetcode 'rank scores' problem(https://leetcode.com/problems/rank-scores/description/):

```
select Score, dense_rank() over (order by Score) Rank
from Scores
order by Score desc
```

It always give me the following error:

```
Line 2: SyntaxError: near '(order by Score) Rank
from Scores
order by Score desc'
```

I wonder how to make this answer correct? Thanks a lot!

Also, I realized most people use an answer without using the DENSE_RANK function, which is quite confusing since to me DENSE_RANK is probably the most intuitive way to solve the problem. Anyone have any idea? Thanks again!

Comment: Not all databases support `dense_rank()`.  Presumably, your does not.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm using Mysql. It doesn't support any window function, if no recent updates.

Comment: MySQL supports window functions including `DENSE_RANK()` in version 8.0, but this version is still in pre-release currently. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_dense-rank

Comment: `Line 2: SyntaxError: near '(order by Score) Rank
from Scores
order by Score desc'` doesn't look like a MySQL error to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited answer

My SQL does not support dense_rank, it does support other window functions though.
Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32494950/are-there-any-functions-in-mysql-like-dense-rank-and-row-number-like-oracle) answer for help.

Alternatively you could run the code in another SQL server

Comment: . . Prior to version 8.0, MySQL supported *no* window functions at all.

Comment: MySQL 8 does support dense_rank: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html along with other window functions.

Comment: Although, even in versions < 8.0, we can easily [emulate DENSE_RANK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52352996/2469308) functionality

Answer (score 0):

Windows function like `rank()`, `dense_rank()` are supported in newer version of MySQL.

Change your SQL query i.e. `as "Rank"` from `as Rank` for passing leetcode testcases.