# MySQL 5.6 - DENSE_RANK like functionality without Order By

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.6

I have a table like this:

```
+------+-----------+
|caseID|groupVarian|
+------+-----------+
|1     |A,B,C,D,E  |
+------+-----------+
|2     |A,B,N,O,P  |
+------+-----------+
|3     |A,B,N,O,P  |
+------+-----------+
|4     |A,B,C,D,F  |
+------+-----------+
|5     |A,B,C,D,E  |
+------+-----------+
```

I would like to get a new column `nameVarian`, such that same `groupVarian` values have same ranking represented by `nameVarian` (eg: v1, v2 and so on). However, `nameVarian` values assigned to a specific `groupVarian` should be as per the order of `caseID` (in the order they appear inside the table).

The output should be something like:

```
+------+-----------+----------+
|caseID|groupVarian|namevarian
+------+-----------+----------+
|1     |A,B,C,D,E  |v1        |
+------+-----------+----------+
|2     |A,B,N,O,P  |v2        |
+------+-----------+----------+
|3     |A,B,N,O,P  |v2        |
+------+-----------+----------+
|4     |A,B,C,D,F  |v3        |
+------+-----------+----------+
|5     |A,B,C,D,E  |v1        |
+------+-----------+----------+
```

Comment: What is your MySQL version ?

Comment: @madhur baiya 5.6

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya ok I'll tried its, thanks before

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For **MySQL version < 8.0** ([OP's version is 5.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52352877/give-value-if-field-per-row-has-value-using-sql/52352996#comment91650801_52352877)):

The problem statement looks like needing [DENSE_RANK](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-dense_rank-function/) functionality over `groupVarian`; however it is not. [As explained by *@Gordon Linoff*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52353634/2469308):

> You appear to want them enumerated by the order they appear in the
>   data.

Assuming that your table name is `t` (please change the table and field name(s) accordingly for your code). Here is an [approach utilizing session variables](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/) (**for older versions of MySQL**), giving the desired result (**[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5yiyp6Zyt2eB5h26RT5Lmf/0)**):

```
SET @row_number = 0;
SELECT t3.caseID, 
       t3.groupVarian, 
       CONCAT('v', t2.num) AS nameVarian
FROM
  (
   SELECT 
     (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num, 
     t1.groupVarian 
   FROM 
     (
      SELECT DISTINCT groupVarian 
      FROM t 
      ORDER BY caseID ASC 
     ) AS t1 
  ) AS t2 
INNER JOIN t AS t3 
  ON t3.groupVarian = t2.groupVarian 
ORDER BY t3.caseID ASC
```

**Additionally:** My earlier attempt to emulate `DENSE_RANK` functionality, works well. Although previous query can also be tweaked slightly to achieve `DENSE_RANK` functionality. However, the following query is more efficient, as it creates **lesser Derived tables**, and avoids **JOIN** on `groupVarian`:

```
SET @row_number = 1;
SET @group_varian = '';

SELECT inner_nest.caseID, 
       inner_nest.groupVarian, 
       CONCAT('v', inner_nest.num) as nameVarian 
FROM (
        SELECT 
            caseID, 
            @row_number:=CASE
                           WHEN @group_varian = groupVarian THEN @row_number
                           ELSE @row_number + 1
                         END AS num, 
            @group_varian:=groupVarian as groupVarian 
        FROM
            t  
        ORDER BY groupVarian
     ) AS inner_nest 
ORDER BY inner_nest.caseID ASC
```

Comment: I was try its but if value in column groupVarian has same value with other row then   name of variant has a same variant name.

Comment: @daud what output are you getting ?

Comment: if value of grupVarian same then value of name varian same for example please see my posting.thanks before for your help

Comment: @daud please post what output you are getting, after running my query ? Ensure that `SET` commands are the start are also run

Comment: @daud I have fixed the query. Please check the edited answer now :)

Comment: Ok @MadhurBhaiya I've check your code and I've edited, Your code is good but still false but I've changed ORDER BY groupVarian to be GROUP BY . Thank you so much for your helped

Comment: @daud what is the final query you are using ? I dont think replacing ORDER BY with GROUP BY will work!

Comment: sorry @MadhurBhaiya when I've changed to be GROUP BY, why row_number + 1 display out **v1, v2, v4, v6, v7** not **v1, v2, v3, v4, v5** ?

Comment: @daud `GROUP BY` wont work. There is just one pending issue in my query, that you need enumeration of groupVarian defined rowwise,

Comment: @daud I am trying to fix this. Will let u know once fixed!

Comment: @daud Finally worked out the solution. Please check the updated answer! Should work 100% :) Dont forget to change the table and field names accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `DENSE_RANK`(MySQL 8.0):

```
SELECT *, CONCAT('v', DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY groupVarian)) AS namevarian
FROM tab
ORDER BY CaseID;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e33fe0637bba69fd30f0811044d639bd)**

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you want to enumerate the variants.  If you just want a number, then you could use the minimum id:

```
select t.*, min_codeId as groupVariantId
from t join
     (select groupVariant, min(codeId) as min_codeId
      from t
      group by groupVariant
     ) g
     on t.groupVariant = g.groupVariant;
```

But that is not quite what you want.  You appear to want them enumerated by the order they appear in the data.  For that, you need variables.  This is a bit tricky, but:

```
select t.*, rn as groupVariantId
from t join
     (select g.*,
             (@rn := if(@gv = groupvariant, @gv,
                        if(@gv := groupvariant, @gv+1, @gv+1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from (select groupVariant, min(codeId) as min_codeId
            from t
            group by groupVariant
            order by min(codeId)
           ) g cross join
           (select @gv := '', @rn := 0) params
     ) g
     on t.groupVariant = g.groupVariant;
```

Using variables is tricky.  One important consideration:  MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in a `SELECT`.  That means that a variable should not be assigned in one expression and then used in another -- because they could be evaluated in the wrong order (another answer has this mistake).

In addition, the `order by` needs to take place in a subquery.  MySQL does not guarantee that the variable assignment occurs before the sorting.