# Ranking system gaps in ranking output

Tags: mysql

I have this project that it ranks different items by their scores, the ranking is okay but it shows gaps when there is a tied score.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT bgycode, scc_bgyscoretotal, FIND_IN_SET( scc_bgyscoretotal, (
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT scc_bgyscoretotal
ORDER BY scc_bgyscoretotal DESC ) FROM bgyprofile)
) AS rank
FROM bgyprofile
```

and it outputs like this:

[image: output]

any way to fix this?
Thanks in advance sorry for the bad english

Comment: add `group by bgycode, scc_bgyscoretotal` at the end of your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need [`Dense_Rank()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_dense-rank) like functionality (available in MySQL **version >= 8.0**). In **older versions of MySQL**, it can be [emulated using Session Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52352996/2469308).

- In a [Derived table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html), determine ranking of a `scc_bgyscoretotal` (highest value having rank 1 and so on). Firstly, get unique values of `scc_bgyscoretotal`, and then determine their ranking using [Session Variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html).
- Now, simply **join** these Derived table to the main table `bgyprofile` using `scc_bgyscoretotal`.

Try the following:

```
SELECT t2.bgycode, 
       t2.scc_bgyscoretotal, 
       dt2.`rank` 
FROM bgyprofile AS t2 
JOIN 
(
 SELECT dt1.scc_bgyscoretotal, 
        @rank_no := @rank_no + 1 AS `rank`  
 FROM 
 (
  SELECT t1.scc_bgyscoretotal 
  FROM bgyprofile AS t1 
  GROUP BY t1.scc_bgyscoretotal 
  ORDER BY t1.scc_bgyscoretotal DESC
 ) AS dt1 
 CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rank_no := 0) AS init1
) AS dt2 ON dt2.scc_bgyscoretotal = t2.scc_bgyscoretotal
```