# PHP: Increment a variable based on change in another variable in foreach loop

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I have a foreach loop that prints the history of line item changes in my application. Each line item has a number, and each line item can have multiple changes.

What I want to do is display the line number alongside each change when my loop executes. `$i` will hold the line number.

```
$i = 1;
foreach($lineItem as $line) {
   echo $i; //line number
   echo $line['field_changed'];
   echo $line['change_date'];
   echo $line['change_from'];
   echo $line['change_to'];
}
```

The code reads from a DB table called `line_item_changes` with the following structure:

```
id  line_id  parent_id
--  -------  ---------
1   2401     521
2   2401     521
3   2401     521
4   2500     521
5   2502     521
6   2502     521
```

I want to increment `$i` every time the value in `$line['line_id']` changes. So that, when the results display, they look something like this:

```
Line #: 1
field: notes
date: 10/9/2018
from: test
to: test2

Line #: 1
field: quantity
date: 10/1/2018
from: 4
to: 3

Line #: 2
field: need_date
date: 10/1/2018
from: 10/24/2018
to: 10/27/2018
```

etc.

Comment: Could you give some more information? From what I understand, you have a table `line_item_changes` and you loop through it, and when line_id changes you want `$i` to increment, is that right? Would this be the result when you loop through `line_item_changes`?: First loop: `1 - 2401` (no changes), then `2 - 2401` (no changes), then `3 - 2401` (no changes), then `4 - 2500` (`line_id` has changed, `$i` will be incremented).

Comment: Yes, that's correct. `$i` should increment by 1 every time `line_id` changes. So the first three changes (2401) would be Line 1 (`$i = 1`), 2500 would be Line 2 (`$i = 2`), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just store the previous `line_id` in a variable, and update `$i` if the value changes. Try the following (explanation in code comments):

```
$i = 1;
$prev_line_id = null; // initializing the previous value

foreach($lineItem as $line) {

   // if the previous line_id exists
   if (isset($prev_line_id)) {

       // if previous value does not match with the current value
       if ($prev_line_id != $line['line_id']) {

           // increment the line number
           $i++;
       }
   }

   // set the previous value
   $prev_line_id = $line['line_id'];

   echo $i; //line number
   echo $line['field_changed'];
   echo $line['change_date'];
   echo $line['change_from'];
   echo $line['change_to'];
}
```

**Note** that you can get the changing line number directly from DB query itself. You can use window functions like `Dense_Rank()`.

Comment: You should set `$prev_line_id` to `$line['line_id']` after you increment `$i`. If you don't do this it will increment `$i` when two `lineItems` with the same `line_id` come after each other in the loop.

Comment: @JeroenGroenveld Infact I moved the setting of previous value outside the loop and we only now to need to check whether previous value matches or not, and increment $i accordingly.

Comment: Worked like a charm after the edit. Many thanks. Perfect solution.

Comment: @Chris happy to help :) You may also consider looking into `dense_rank()` and get this line number directly from DB itself.

Comment: I would be interested in figuring out how to incorporate that into my code. Unfortunately, MySQL does not support the dense_rank() function.

Comment: @Chris MySQL version >= 8.0 does support it. Your version may be 5+ . Anyways it can be emulated. Check one of my answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52352996/2469308

This will give u some idea. You may create a new question, and you will definitely get answers for your version of MySQL

Comment: @Chris Look at the end - Additionally part in the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52352996/2469308

Answer (score 1):

You have to store the last `line_id` of the last loop and then check it with the `line_id` of the next loop, if they are not equal then increment `$i`, when `$i` is incremented you set `$prev_line_id` to the current `line_id`.

```
$prev_line_id = $lineItem[0]['line_id'] ?? null;
$i = 0;
foreach($lineItem  as $line)
{
    if($line['line_id'] != $prev_line_id )
    {
        $i++;
        $prev_line_id = $line['line_id'];
    }

    echo $i; //line number
    echo $line['field_changed'];
    echo $line['change_date'];
    echo $line['change_from'];
    echo $line['change_to'];
}
```