# DateDiff in MySQL with same column

Tags: mysql, datediff

I have a table 'orders' that looks like this:

```
+---------------+--------------+------------+
| customer_name | order_number |    date    |
+---------------+--------------+------------+
| jack          |            1 | 2018-01-01 |
| jack          |            2 | 2018-01-06 |
| jack          |            3 | 2018-01-19 |
| jack          |            4 | 2018-01-06 |
| jack          |            5 | 2018-02-27 |
| jack          |            6 | 2018-02-02 |
+---------------+--------------+------------+
```

Now, I want a table that gives me the difference in the consecutive dates in days. Like so:

```
+------------+------------+------+
|    date    | next_date  | diff |
+------------+------------+------+
| 2018-01-01 | 2018-01-06 |    5 |
| 2018-01-06 | 2018-01-06 |    0 |
| 2018-01-06 | 2018-01-19 |   13 |
| 2018-01-19 | 2018-02-02 |   14 |
| 2018-02-02 | 2018-02-27 |   25 |
+------------+------------+------+
```

The query I used is this:

```
SELECT orders.date, MIN(table1.date) FROM orders
    LEFT JOIN orders table1
    on orders.customer_name = table1.customer_name
    AND table1.date >= orders.date
    AND table1.order_number !=  orders.order_number
    WHERE orders.customer_name = 'jack'
    GROUP BY orders.order_number, orders.date
    ORDER BY orders.date;
```

This is the ouptput:

```
+------------+------------+
|    date    | next_date  |
+------------+------------+
| 2018-01-01 | 2018-01-06 |
| 2018-01-06 | 2018-01-06 |
| 2018-01-06 | 2018-01-06 |
| 2018-01-19 | 2018-02-02 |
| 2018-02-02 | 2018-02-27 |
| 2018-02-27 |    NULL    |
+------------+------------+
```

As you can see there are a a few issues.

1. There are two rows where the `date` and `next_date` are both `2018-01-06`.
2. There is no row where the `next_date` is 2018-01-19`
3. The last row has a NULL value for `next_date`
4. How do I get difference in date in days?

I know this is happening because I have grouped by order_number and `>=`
but I don't know how else to approach this. I feel like there is an obvious easy solution to this that is evading me. Any help?

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/be23c0/1)

In case SQL Fiddle doesn't work:

```
CREATE TABLE orders
    (`customer_name` varchar(4), `order_number` int, `date` varchar(10))
;

INSERT INTO orders
    (`customer_name`, `order_number`, `date`)
VALUES
    ('jack', 1, '2018-01-01'),
    ('jack', 2, '2018-01-06'),
    ('jack', 3, '2018-01-19'),
    ('jack', 4, '2018-01-06'),
    ('jack', 5, '2018-02-27'),
    ('jack', 6, '2018-02-02')
;
```

Comment: If there is no next order data; last row next date should be null only; unless you want that date value to be same as the date column

Comment: is 2018-01-06 row with 0 diff valid result here? Do you expect to see that?

Comment: @rs.Yep, I do expect to see it.

Comment: @krthkskmr, what happens if we have another 2018-01-06 with order_number 7, you expect two rows with 0 diff?

Comment: @rs. Exactly! Basically, don't calculate the difference in dates if it's already been calculated for that order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested on a non **ROW_NUMBER()** solution depending on **MySQL 8.x** or greater, check next explanation.

**EXPLANATION:**

**1)** First, we select all dates from the **orders** table, ordering they by ascending and assigning a virtual auto-incrementet ID to each date. We going to get something like this:

```
SELECT (@row_number := @row_number + 1) AS orderNum, date 
FROM ORDERS, (SELECT @row_number:=0) AS t
ORDER BY date;

Output:
1   2018-01-01
2   2018-01-06
3   2018-01-06
4   2018-01-19
5   2018-02-02
6   2018-02-27
```

**2)** We create a similar query to the previous one, but this time we discard the first row, like this:

```
SELECT (@row_number2 := @row_number2 + 1) AS orderNum, date
FROM ORDERS, (SELECT @row_number2 := 0) AS t
ORDER BY date
LIMIT 999999999999
OFFSET 1;

Output:
1   2018-01-06
2   2018-01-06
3   2018-01-19
4   2018-02-02
5   2018-02-27
```

The only problem here, is we have to hardcode the LIMIT number to a sufficiently high number, so we can assure we will select all rows except the first one.

**3)** At this point, you should be thinking on joining the both previous results by the virtually generated ID. So, lets see the final query:

```
SELECT
    startDate.date AS date,
    nextDate.date AS next_date,
    DATEDIFF(nextDate.date, startDate.date) AS diff
FROM
    (SELECT (@row_number := @row_number + 1) AS orderNum, date 
     FROM ORDERS, (SELECT @row_number:=0) AS t
     ORDER BY date) AS startDate
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT (@row_number2 := @row_number2 + 1) AS orderNum, date
     FROM ORDERS, (SELECT @row_number2 := 0) AS t
     ORDER BY date
     LIMIT 999999999999
     OFFSET 1) AS nextDate ON nextDate.orderNum = startDate.orderNum;

Output:
2018-01-01  2018-01-06  5
2018-01-06  2018-01-06  0
2018-01-06  2018-01-19  13
2018-01-19  2018-02-02  14
2018-02-02  2018-02-27  25
```

You can see the working example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1572ea/27

Answer (score 1):

- There is no direct correlation between order_number and date. Even higher value of order_number is having lower date.
- So, we cannot use order_number to determine next_date.
- Since your [MySQL version is 8.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52862381/datediff-in-mysql-with-same-column/52862446#comment92639747_52862446), we can do a smart utilization of [`Row_Number()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) functionality.
- We will use the `orders` table twice into two different [Derived Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html), with row numbers assigned based on ascending order of the `date`. The difference between the two will be that one of the table will have modified row numbers (incremented by 1).
- Now, all we need to do is **inner join** between them, based on the row number values. Due to this "sliding gap" between the row numbers, we will get "current" and "next" date. Inner join will also ensure that the last "current" date row where there is no matching "next" date, will not come.
- Eventually, we can use the [`DateDiff()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) function to determine the difference between the dates.

Try the following:

```
SELECT t.`date`, 
       next_t.`date` AS next_date, 
       DATEDIFF(next_t.`date`, t.`date`) AS diff 
FROM 
(
  SELECT 1 + (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY `date` ASC)) AS rn, 
          `date`  
  FROM orders 
  WHERE customer_name = 'jack'
) AS t

JOIN 

(
  SELECT (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY `date` ASC)) AS rn, 
          `date`  
  FROM orders 
  WHERE customer_name = 'jack'
) AS next_t ON next_t.rn = t.rn
```

### [DB Fiddle DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nGAr4YEKK6XtEgjisMy7tJ/0)

Comment: @krthkskmr check the updated answer. Also, if you could provide a SQL fiddle or DB fiddle; it would be easier to play and fix the query

Comment: I don't want use a `>` operator on order_number because it can be randomized. The issue is that there are two instance with `2018-01-06`. I need `t2.date >= t1.date` condition. But when I do that I don't get the row where `2018-01-19` is the `date`

Comment: @krthkskmr I understand the randomizing part. Can you create a SQL or DB fiddle ? This looks like a Window function problem. What is your MySQL server version ?

Comment: MySQL version 8.0.11. Added the SQL Fiddle link.

Comment: @krthkskmr SQL Fiddle is not opening for me; It behaves on its own at time. Can you edit the question to add `create table` and `insert` queries

Comment: Added the Create and Insert queries.

Comment: Perfect! How would one do this if they had an older version of MySQL? (Just curious)

Comment: @krthkskmr It is doable in older versions using Session variables. I have written quite a bit of similar answers on them same. For eg: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/52352996/2469308

Do consider marking this answer as accepted (green tick). Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way. But your `order 4` has a `previous date` than `order 3`. So it will yield a negative.

```
SELECT customer_name,order_number,date,
LEAD(date) OVER (ORDER BY customer_name,order_number) next_date,
ISNULL(DATEDIFF(DAY,date,LEAD(date) OVER (ORDER BY customer_name,order_number)),0) AS diff
FROM #orders
```

Comment: This sounds better solution for MySQL 8.x version

Comment: Getting error: Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ISNULL'

Problem here is that in OP's data there is no linear correlation between order_number and date.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I think using date instead of order_number should work Ex: `SELECT `date`, LEAD(`date`) OVER W AS next_date, DATEDIFF(LEAD(`date`) OVER W , `date`)  AS diff FROM orders where `customer_name` = 'jack' WINDOW W AS (ORDER BY `date`);`    fiddle link: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nGAr4YEKK6XtEgjisMy7tJ/0