# MYSQL rank with ties Implementing Problems

Tags: mysql, ranking

I am trying to implement the solution from a four year old solution to a question and not having any success. Here is what I am using:

```
SELECT NAME, 
    sum(STaCResults.masterpoints) AS STaCResults.totalMasterpoints, 
    STaCResults.city_state,
    @prev := @curr, 
    @curr := STaCResults.totalMasterpoints, 
    @rank := IF(@prev = @curr, @rank, @rank + @i) AS rank, 
    IF(@prev <> STaCResults.totalMasterpoints, @i:=1, @i:=@i+1) AS counter
FROM STaCResults
GROUP BY NAME
ORDER BY STaCResults.totalMasterpoints desc
```

The database contains names, city_state and a masterpoint total for the year which gets summed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: provide you tables schema, dataset sample and expected result

Comment: This query seams not to be valid ANSI SQL but using MySQL´s extended GROUP BY "feature"  .. The column `STaCResults.city_state` can hold invalid results with invalid i mean values not related to the group name..

Comment: Please provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output. Refer this link on how to frame a good SQL question: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: If you are looking for a Dense_rank() like solution, you may check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52352996/2469308