# MySQL error: expecting EOF ";" instead of ")"

Tags: mysql, window-functions

I have this code:

```
SELECT
    date_created,
    serial_number,
    dense_rank() OVER ( PARTITION BY serial_number ORDER BY date_created DESC) AS "rank",
FROM table_A
;
```

And I am getting this error:

> ")" is not valid at this position, expecting EOF, ";"

I don't understadn why I am getting this error, I take the syntax from this web:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mysql-partition-by-clause/

I already tried taking of the comma after "rank", because as far as I know there shouldn't be commas before the FROM statement. But the same error appears.

Any idea of what's happening?

EDIT: it is popssible that I cannot use dense_rank() because my user in this database doesn't have the permission to do that? There are many things I cannot do (for example to use INTO OUTFILE). Maybe I cannot use windows and first of all it doesn't recognize `dense_rank()`. In addition, the keyword "OVER" doesn't appear in blue in my MySQL Workbench.

Comment: just delete  comma  after rank :)

Comment: I already tried this but the same error appears. It is possible to don't have the permission of using Windows with my user? I know my user doesn't have full control in this database, could be that? I'm pretty new using MySQL and in spite of I know the syntax of SQL I don't know a lot of things about the environment. Thank u!

Comment: share table_A create statement and insert statements to help us find the solution,

Comment: I haven't created the table, I don't have access to the code where the table is created.

Comment: 1) Remove excess comma; 2) Replace doublequotes with backticks. 3) `")" is not valid at this position, expecting EOF, ";"` is **NOT** MySQL error message. Search the problem in your program code.

Comment: `DENSE_RANK()` is a window function  and window function are introduced in `MySQL 8`, which version are you using ?

Comment: So that answers the question, I am using 5.7 version.

Comment: @Miquel check : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52352877/mysql-5-6-dense-rank-like-functionality-without-order-by it might help

Answer (score 0):

The error comes to the fact that I am using the 5.7 version and windows functions were introduced in the 8 version.