# MySQL: ROW_NUMBER () counts duplicates as separate rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables. Table of employees `Employee` and departments `Department`.

The `Employee` table looks like this:

```
+----+-------+--------+--------------+
| Id | Name  | Salary | DepartmentId |

+----+-------+--------+--------------+

| 1  | Joe   | 85000  | 1            |

| 2  | Henry | 80000  | 2            |

| 3  | Sam   | 60000  | 2            |

| 4  | Max   | 90000  | 1            |

| 5  | Janet | 69000  | 1            |

| 6  | Randy | 85000  | 1            |

| 7  | Will  | 70000  | 1            |

+----+-------+--------+--------------+
```

The `Department` table looks like this:

```
+----+----------+
| Id | Name     |
+----+----------+
| 1  | IT       |
| 2  | Sales    |
+----+----------+
```

I want to write a query that for each department will output employees and a number indicating the salary rating. (If the salary is the maximum in the department, the number is 1. ***If there are two identical salaries in the department, then their rating number must be the same***).

I implemented this query using the window function `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT 
  d.Name Department, 
  e.Name Employee, 
  e.Salary,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY d.Name 
      ORDER BY e.Salary DESC
  ) SalaryRating,
FROM
  Employee e 
LEFT JOIN Department d 
  ON e.DepartmentId = d.Id;
```

This query outputs the following data:

```
Department  Employee    Salary  SalaryRating
IT          Max         90000   1
IT          Joe         85000   2
IT          Randy       85000   3
IT          Will        70000   4
IT          Janet       69000   5
Sales       Henry       80000   1
Sales       Sam         60000   2
```

There is a mistake. Randy `SalaryRating` value is `3`, but it should be `2`, because he has the same salary as Joe.

What is the error in my query? How to fix it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32494950/are-there-any-functions-in-mysql-like-dense-rank-and-row-number-like-oracle

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html

Answer (score 3):

You can use `DENSE_RANK`

```
  SELECT 
      d.Name Department, 
      e.Name Employee, 
      e.Salary,
      DENSE_RANK() OVER (
          PARTITION BY d.Name 
          ORDER BY e.Salary DESC
      ) SalaryRating,
    FROM
      Employee e 
    LEFT JOIN Department d 
      ON e.DepartmentId = d.Id;
```