# Mysql giving ranks to the students based on score

Tags: mysql

I have a table called contests :

```
+-------+-------+------+
| name  | Points | Rank |
+-------+-------+------+
| Stud1 |    50 |    0 |
| Stud2 |    40 |    0 |
| Stud3 |    20 |    0 |
| Stud4 |    20 |    0 |
| Stud5 |    15 |    0 |
| Stud6 |    10 |    0 |
+-------+-------+------+
```

Points column will keep on updating with points ans rank will be generated according  depends upon points .

Please help me in doing this .

I tried this http://stackoverflow.com/a/1320196/1816093

Comment: What didn't work for you in the given answer ?

Comment: That is to sort already existed ranks , But i am trying to generate rank value .

Comment: `rank will be generated according depends upon points` which means rank is computed column in your schema. it's actually not got design to store inferred value into another column

Comment: @Yaman Yes exactly , It is a computed column based upon score .Thanks for understanding  . Ho do i implement that. Can u help me?

Comment: Don't store rank. Just calculate it on-the-fly

Comment: then @Vijay the link which you have given should work. What's the error which you are getting when you execute the stackoverflow link mentioned above

Comment: @jain it is skipping the order of ranks . if there are two 3 and 3 ranks then next should  be 4 , but it is coming as 5

Answer (score 1):

Don't store rank. Just calculate it on-the-fly...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(name VARCHAR(12) PRIMARY KEY,points INT NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
('Stud1',50),
('Stud2',40),
('Stud3',20),
('Stud4',20),
('Stud5',15),
('Stud6',10);
```

Solution 1:

```
SELECT x.*
     , FIND_IN_SET(points,(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT points ORDER BY points DESC) FROM my_table)) n 
  FROM my_table x;
+-------+--------+------+
| name  | points | n    |
+-------+--------+------+
| Stud1 |     50 |    1 |
| Stud2 |     40 |    2 |
| Stud3 |     20 |    3 |
| Stud4 |     20 |    3 |
| Stud5 |     15 |    4 |
| Stud6 |     10 |    5 |
+-------+--------+------+
```

Solution 2:

```
SELECT x.*
     , CASE WHEN @prev = points THEN @i:=@i ELSE @i:=@i+1 END rank
     , @prev := points FROM my_table x
     , (SELECT @prev:=null,@i:=0) vars 
 ORDER 
    BY points
     , name;
+-------+--------+------+-----------------+
| name  | points | rank | @prev := points |
+-------+--------+------+-----------------+
| Stud6 |     10 |    1 |              10 |
| Stud5 |     15 |    2 |              15 |
| Stud3 |     20 |    3 |              20 |
| Stud4 |     20 |    3 |              20 |
| Stud2 |     40 |    4 |              40 |
| Stud1 |     50 |    5 |              50 |
+-------+--------+------+-----------------+
```

Comment: there is no option to give 10000K thums up :)

Comment: I think you just did ;-)